# Wrapping groups of lists within divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, list

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<ul>
    <li class="group4">
        <ul class="group2">
            <li class="first">stuff</li>
            <li class="last">stuff</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="group2">
            <li class="first">stuff</li>
            <li class="last">stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="group4">
        <ul class="group2">
            <li class="first">stuff</li>
            <li class="last">stuff</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="group2">
            <li class="first">stuff</li>
            <li class="last">stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm currently equipped with:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">stuff</li>
    <li class="last">stuff</li>
    <li class="first">stuff</li>
    <li class="last">stuff</li>
    <li class="first">stuff</li>
    <li class="last">stuff</li>
    <li class="first">stuff</li>
    <li class="last">stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Essentially this will make the list items appear in rows of 4, and rows of 2 in mobile view.

I can't hardcode this since the list items are retrieved via php.

Is there a script or something that can help me do this?

Comment: So, you want to generate invalid HTML? http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

Comment: @TiesonT. oh, or would it be better to wrap it in ul?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-content-model

Comment: The only permitted immediate child elements of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` are `<li>`. You can do something like ul > li > div > your content.

Comment: @TiesonT. ok edited the code.. should make more sense now

Comment: you changed your question after I answered! :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $ul = $('ul').find('.first').each(function() {
   $(this).next('.last').addBack().wrapAll('<ul class="group2"/>');
}).end();

while( $ul.children('.group2').length )
   $ul.children('.group2').slice(0, 2).wrapAll('<li class="group4"/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Twr9z/

Answer (score 0):

this will do what you want, plus preserving the W3C validation:

```
$('.first').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).data('wrapped')){
        $(this).wrap('<ul class="group2"></ul>');
        $(this).parent('.group2').append($(this).parent('.group2').nextAll('.last:first').clone()).html();

        $(this).parent('.group2').nextAll('.last:first').remove();
        $(this).parent('.group2').wrap('<li class="group4"></li>');
        $(this).data('wrapped',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: nice, but this would leave a '.last' LI after every 'group' see here > http://jsfiddle.net/aR3EF/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it if you don't know how many items will be in each group:

```
function relist() {
    var list = $("ul.list");
    var li = list.children("li");
    var _li, _ul, item;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            item = list.find("li:eq(" + i + "), li:eq(" + parseInt(i - 1) + ")");
            _ul = $("<ul class='group_" + item.length + "'></ul>");
            item.wrapAll(_ul);
        }
    }
    var ul = list.find("ul");
    for (var j = 0; j < ul.length; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 1) {
            item = list.find("ul:eq(" + j + "), ul:eq(" + parseInt(j - 1) + ")");
            _li = $("<li class='group_" + item.find('li').length + "'></li>");
            item.wrapAll(_li);
        }
    }
}

$(function () {    relist()});
```

The name of the classes will be group + the number of items under it.